# why are ifs different colours on jupyterlab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I was wondering why those two `ifs` aren't both green or both red:
[image]

There is no error when I execute the script. I know it's not that big of a deal but it's still bothering me a little.

Here is the code if you want to try it locally:

```
def ellipplot(P,gamma=None,xc=None):
  """ELLIPPLOT Internal function for plotting ellipsoid"""

  if xc is None:
    xc = np.zeros(len(P))
  if gamma is None:
    gamma = 1
```

Comment: The Jupyter notebook code indentation is `4` spaces by default. You are using `2` spaces. Have you changed the indentationUnit in your configuration? For me, it turns green if I use `4` spaces. Why it is only for the second if, I do not know.

Comment: You are absolutely right, using an indentation of `4` spaces did solve the red one. I don't think I mind that much why one's red and one's green now that they're all green to be fair. I just indented everything with `4` spaces and I don't have any weird colours like the one is the example  provided anymore.